# Convert string html to IView in Asp.Net core

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using the `ViewContext` of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering` package to further render the html as follows:

```
using (var output = new StringWriter())
            {
                var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                    actionContext,
                    view,
                    new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(
                        metadataProvider: new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(),
                        modelState: new ModelStateDictionary())
                    {
                        Model = model
                    },
                    new TempDataDictionary(
                        actionContext.HttpContext,
                        _tempDataProvider),
                    output,
                    new HtmlHelperOptions());


                await view.RenderAsync(viewContext);
}
```

Here the second parameter is view which according to various sources, can be obtained by following:

```
var view = _viewEngine.FindView(..); //or GetView() or GetPage()
```

But I have a plain HTML string like this,

```
string htmlTemplate = <p>Hello, @Model.Name</p>
```

For `viewcontext` I need to convert this string to IView type. In earlier version, `Razor.Parse(htmlString)` used to do the job but I am stuck here in core as I am not getting any source or reference to convert string html to IView.

How to convert string Html to IView object?

Comment: Did you found solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: I found: https://long2know.com/2017/08/rendering-and-emailing-embedded-razor-views-with-net-core/